Any reference or name to the inequality $\min(x,y)\geq x-\frac{x^2}{4y}$ for $x>0,y>0$.
I came across the inequality
$$
\min(x,y)\geq x-\frac{x^2}{4y}
$$
in statistics where it is used to give a lower bound of a minimum in terms of its second moment. Wondering the name or any related inequality of this type.
Proof.
If $\min(x,y)=x$, then its trivial. Assume $\min(x,y)=y$, then
$$
y\geq x-x^2/4y\implies 4y^2-4yx+x^2\geq 0 \iff (x-2y)^2\geq 0.
$$

Your inequality is correct only if $x,y \ge 0$.

$y > 0$ is sufficient, I think.

@NN2 It's written in the title but OP did not include it in the body of the question

@MartinR, you are right, $y>0$ is sufficient.

If $,y>0,,,$ then $$\begin{cases}y\geqslant y-\left(\dfrac x{2\sqrt y}-\sqrt y\right)^{!2}!=x-\dfrac{x^2}{4y}\x\geqslant x-\dfrac{x^2}{4y}\end{cases}$$hence ,$;;\color{blue}{\min(x,y)\geqslant x-\dfrac{x^2}{4y}},.;;$

On the other hand, if $;y<0,,,$ then $$\color{blue}{\min(x,y)\leqslant x\leqslant x-\dfrac{x^2}{4y}},.$$

$argmax_{x} (x-\frac{x^2}{4y}) = 2y \implies \max_{x} (x-\frac{x^2}{4y})  = y$
